# psycopg2 use dict+dict or dict+variable for binding variables into insert query

Tags: psycopg2

I have dict and variable outside of query. I use interpolation for 
binding variables like this:

```
self.cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO
        items (sku, external_id, url, price, in_stock, title, created_at)
    VALUES
        (%(sku)s, %(external_id)s, %(url)s,  %(price)s, %(in_stock)s, %(title)s, now()) RETURNING id
    """, item)
```

Now I want to add additional field to query which is not in the object, but variable calculated before, like this:

```
retailer_id = self.retailer_ids[item.name] # <- here we go!
self.cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO
        items (sku, external_id, url, price, in_stock, title, created_at, retailer_id)
    VALUES
        (%(sku)s, %(external_id)s, %(url)s,  %(price)s, %(in_stock)s, %(title)s, now(), %s) RETURNING id
    """, (item, retailer_id,))
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried many approaches but none of them are working.

So I decided to workaround, convert my object into dict and add retailer_id to it manually, like this:

```
retailer_id = self.retailer_ids[item.name]
item_dict = dict(item)
item_dict['retailer_id'] = retailer_id
try:
    self.cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO
            items (sku, external_id, url, price, in_stock, title, created_at, retailer_id)
        VALUES
            (%(sku)s, %(external_id)s, %(url)s,  %(price)s, %(in_stock)s, %(title)s, now(), %(retailer_id)s) RETURNING id
        """, item_dict)
```

And obviously, it was working.

Now I'm curious, is it possible to compose query using dict+variable or two dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not

Insert other 29 characters here.